# Reading data from a Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

**Trying to initialize Firebase child data to MutableList**

[**Database screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SJX4.png)

**Code**

```
    class RecipesItemRepository {
    private val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("recipes").child("test")
    var recipesItem = MutableLiveData<List<RecipesItem>>()

    fun onViewInitializedProducts() {
        val postListener = object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val recipesData = ArrayList<RecipesItem>()
                dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                    recipesData.add(it.getValue(RecipesItem::class.java)!!)
                }
                recipesItem.value = recipesData
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("tag", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener)
    }



        fun getChildrenByParent(parent: String): List<RecipesItem> {
            onViewInitializedProducts()
            var recipes = recipesItem.value
            val children = mutableListOf<RecipesItem>()
            recipes?.forEach {
                if (it.parent == parent) {
                    children.add(it)
                }
            }
            return children
        }
    }
```

**Error**

Here's the log of App Running. I have this error while trying to intent RecyclerView fragment

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.cookhelper, PID: 14895
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.cookhelper.navigation.recipes.RecipesItem
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:423)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:212)
        at com.example.cookhelper.navigation.recipes.RecipesItemRepository$onViewInitializedProducts$postListener$1.onDataChange(RecipesItemRepository.kt:39)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:183)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

**Magic**

Getting data from Firebase is not working, so I've tried to add local data to list and it worked properly:

```
class RecipesItemRepository {

    val recipesData = mutableListOf<RecipesItem>(
        RecipesItem(
            1,
            "Burger",
            "Food",
            "https://www.insurancejournal.com/app/uploads/2019/11/impossible-burger-2-768x579.jpg",
            "Dinner"
        ),
        RecipesItem(
            2,
            "Fried Chicken",
            "Food",
            "https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/fried-chicken-ghk-0619-1558621360.jpg?crop=0.808xw:0.808xh;0.0663xw,0.0976xh&resize=980:*",
            "Evening dinner"
        )
    )

        fun getChildrenByParent(parent: String): List<RecipesItem> {
            val children = mutableListOf<RecipesItem>()
            val recipes = recipesData
            recipes?.forEach {
                if (it.parent == parent) {
                    children.add(it)
                }
            }
            return children
        }
    }
```

This might be an error while getting data from firebase, because local data is displayed! Data is initialized in recycler view if this would be important.

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    fun onViewInitializedProducts() {
        val postListener = object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val recipesData = ArrayList<RecipesItem>()
                dataSnapshot.children.forEach {
                    recipesData.add(it.getValue(RecipesItem::class.java)!!)
                }
                recipesItem.value = recipesData
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("tag", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener)
    }
```

into this:

```
    fun onViewInitializedProducts() {
        val postListener = object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val recipesData = ArrayList<RecipesItem>()
                    recipesData.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(RecipesItem::class.java)!!)
                recipesItem.value = recipesData
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("tag", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException())
            }
        }
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener)
    }
```

Remove the `forEach` since when you are iterating, you are retrieving a String from the database and not an object of type `RecipesItem`.